Coding in Assembly instead of using tools like godbolt to convert high level programming languages to assembly
Recently, I thought why are there Assembly Language devs as we can convert the code of c++ or other high level languages to assembly and then use assembly from there directly as a low level code.
Like if there is a code in c++ which does a task assume a function "A" and we write code in assembly that also does same thing so we can use those both but assembly is way faster and efficient so instead of writing code in assembly that does function "A" can't we just convert that c++ code to assembly via tools like godbolt that does that task.
Is it because that compiled or interpreted code is not independent, like if there cpp code takes input doesn't that converted code to assembly can also do same independently instead of involving cpp again
I have tried assembly and cpp so i thought of this idea

Though compilers keep improving, there are still things that you can instruct the chip to do from assembly level that the compilers do not (yet?) support.

Godbolt is showing you what the compiler is doing. The assembly code you see is exactly what will be in the executable - it's not faster or slower, it is exactly that. Only if you can outsmart the compiler and write better assembly can you get a speed improvement.

once you have the assembly it doesnt matter whether it was produced by a compiler or handwritten. In principle you could write the same code that the compiler produces. If you find the the output of a compiler can be improved you'd file a feature request / bug report

Another argument against: the available instruction set and even the timings of certain instructions can vary per CPU. If you want the "way faster and more efficient" code all the time it really pays to recompile using flags appropriate to the target system. As a recent example of this, see the Intel AVX10 extension.

When I got my first optimizing compiler ($6000 back then; open source these days), I took my assembly routines and wrote the equivalent in C.  I was expecting my assembly routines would be much faster than the optimized C code.  The optimizing compiler did all my assembly tricks, and a few more that I didn't see, and was significantly faster (10% faster) than my own assembly code.  Also, the C code took me about 30 minutes to write, my assembly code took me 40 hours to write.  That was the last time I programmed in assembly.

I used to do assembly too but no. You probably can't do better then the compiler and if you can probably only one ONE platform. The compiler can keep track of many aspect of the CPU knowledge (e.g. how it pipelines, how it can do streaming instructions, etc). Speed is nowadays found much more in proper data-structure design taking into account cache-locality etc.  And in fact the last few times I did try to optimize some code by hand... it wasn't faster because the code was memory bandwidth limited anyway. So no do not prematurely optimize.

You might want to watch this (one of my favority cppcon videos ever) : CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”

"why are there Assembly Language devs" -- Are there still assembly language devs? How many? You ask the question as if it's common to write assembly, but it's been a niche market for decades.

"convert that c++ code to assembly via tools like godbolt that does that task" -- It would be more direct to suggest the tools used by Compiler Explorer (godbolt), such as gcc and clang.

A C++ compiler produces assembly that is then used to generate binary. If you write the same asm by hand and then use an assembler to generate the same binary, then there's no difference. The main difference is that the compiler is usually a lot better at generating ASM than most people. Writing asm by hand is usually pointless (or actually detrimental) in 99.999% of all cases.

Nowadays, there is less requirements to program in assembly, but there is still a need to understand assembly language, especially in the world of embedded systems.  The truth of your C++ code is in the compiler's assembly listing.

The challenge is how to get the compiler to generate assembly language using those special processor instructions.  This is usually faster than writing the assembly language by hand.

Assembly is not inherently faster than C++ or any other (compiled) programming language.
Rather, the point is that handwritten assembly can be better than the one produced by the C++ compiler if you're better at writing it than the compiler.
Most of us aren't better at it, and 99% of the time the optimization isn't worth the development time.

And if you can outperform the compiler, what of the next maintainer of the program? Do you really want to maintain the same project for the next 40 years?
